# jQuery .submit() won't execute no matter what

Tags: jquery, submit

I have a page which contains two forms, both with an unique ID. I need to make the page fade out when either of the forms is submitted. However, it won't work.

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#container').fadeOut(0);
        $('#container').fadeIn(500);
    });

    $('form').submit(function(){
        alert("Hello.");
        $('#container').fadeOut(500);
    });
```

As you can see from the code, it should show an alert but it does not, and it doesn't even fade out the page.
My forms contain a text input, which is set to readonly, and a submit button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alternatively, I'd like to know if there's a way to fade out a page when an user leaves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').fadeOut(0);
    $('#container').fadeIn(500);

    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        $('#container').fadeOut(500, function() { 
            form.submit();
        });       
    });
});
```

The submit binding was outside of the document ready and it probably couldn't find the form tag when it was executed.

jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/KbaG3/

Comment: Thanks, but the page still won't fade out. It looks like the fadeOut is ignored and the browser skips to the next page directly.

Comment: I've updated the answer and added a jsfiddle example to do what you want. It now stops the submit event and then manually submits the form after fading out the container.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move the submit event register function to inside the document ready function so that you can be sure the DOM is ready before registering the function.

If that doesn't help, see if there are any javascript errors being thrown on the page which might halt the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're including this JS at the bottom of the page, you should move the `$(form)....` code inside the `$(document).ready()` block

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#container').fadeOut(0);
        $('#container').fadeIn(500);


    $('form').submit(function(){
        alert("Hello.");
        $('#container').fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

This is because your element doesn't exist when you are binding the event to it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#container').hide().fadeIn(500);

    $('form').submit(function(){
        alert("Hello.");
        $('#container').fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

I think is a cleaner code and and also no conflict proof.